# how to add an object to existing json file using jq

Tags: json, jq

I have an empty output.json and I want to populate it with {key, value} pairs where key is a string and value is a Json array read from file.  I need to go through this for multiple files to populate the output.json.   So far, value is being populated successfuly.

```
$ jq --argjson cves "$(cat my-scan-result-N.json)" '.+={"TODO": $cves}' output.json
{
  "TODO": [
    {
      "cvePK": "CVE-2020-11656",
      "summary": "In SQLite through 3.31.1, the ALTER TABLE implementation has a use-after-free, as demonstrated by an ORDER BY clause that belongs to a compound SELECT statement.",
      "cvss": 7.5,
      "notes": ""
    },
    {
      "cvePK": "CVE-2019-19646",
      "summary": "pragma.c in SQLite through 3.30.1 mishandles NOT NULL in an integrity_check PRAGMA command in certain cases of generated columns.",
      "cvss": 7.5,
      "notes": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

However, when I add another `--argjson` to populate the key ("TODO") with desired value `$FQDN`, it fails with an error.

```
$ FQIN="example.com/foo/bar:7.0.3"  # Tried \""example.com/foo/bar:7.0.3"\" as well but doesn't work.

$ jq --argjson cves "$(cat my-scan-result.json)" --argjson fqin="FQIN" '.+={$fqin: $cves}' output.json


C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\jq\tools\jq.exe: invalid JSON text passed to --argjson
Use C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\jq\tools\jq.exe --help for help with command-line options,
or see the jq manpage, or online docs  at https://stedolan.github.io/jq
```

So my goal is to have something like below, but above error message is not helpful enough.   Any help would be appreciated.

```
{
  "example.com/foo/bar:7.0.3": [
    {
      "cvePK": "CVE-2020-11656",
      "summary": "In SQLite through 3.31.1, the ALTER TABLE implementation has a use-after-free, as demonstrated by an ORDER BY clause that belongs to a compound SELECT statement.",
      "cvss": 7.5,
      "notes": ""
    },
    {
      "cvePK": "CVE-2019-19646",
      "summary": "pragma.c in SQLite through 3.30.1 mishandles NOT NULL in an integrity_check PRAGMA command in certain cases of generated columns.",
      "cvss": 7.5,
      "notes": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The line:

> ```
> jq --argjson cves "$(cat my-scan-result.json)" --argjson fqin="FQIN" '.+={$fqin: $cves}' output.json
> ```

has several errors:

1. The phrase `--argjson fqin="FQIN"` is incorrect.  Please see the jq manual for details.  Suffice it to say here that you could achieve the desired effect by writing `--arg fqin "$FQIN"`.
2. The jq expression `{$fqin: $cves}` is incorrect.  When a key name is specified using a variable, the variable must be enclosed in parentheses: `{($fqin): $cves}`.  (Indeed, whenever the key name is specified indirectly, the specifying expression must be enclosed in parentheses.)

Comment: This is awesome.   

1. Yes, the syntax was wrong.  I overlooked at the syntax.<br/>

2. (${fqin}): and this was the culprit whole time. 

Much appreciated your help, @peak!

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
FQIN="example.com/foo/bar:7.0." jq -n --argjson cves "$(cat my-scan-result.json)" '.+={(env.FQIN): $cves}'
```